# BeforeUpdate Access VBA in form field can only enter number

Tags: vba, ms-access, type-mismatch, isnull, beforeupdate

I have a form where I want either Asset or Location filled out and Supervisor or Lead or Crew or Work Group or Crew Work Group. I have the code and it works but it only allows me to enter numbers into these fields. I want to be able to enter numbers and letters into these fields.

```
 Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)


 If IsNull(Form_frmAddPM.Asset Or Form_frmAddPM.Location) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a value in an asset or location."
    Cancel = True
  End If


 If IsNull(Form_frmAddPM.Supervisor Or Form_frmAddPM.Lead Or 
    Form_frmAddPM.Crew Or Form_frmAddPM.Work_Group Or 
     Form_frmAddPM.Crew_Work_Group) Then
     MsgBox "Please enter value in Supervisor, Lead, Crew, Work Group, or 
     Crew 
        Work Group."
        Cancel = True

      End If

End Sub
```

I have tried to change integer to different types. With the code above when I try to enter letters into the form a mismatch type error pops up.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the bitwise `OR` operator, which requires both values you use it on to be an integer (see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/logical-and-bitwise-operators#bitwise-operations), VB.Net but works the same in VBA)

Instead, you should check for each field if it's null separately:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)


 If IsNull(Form_frmAddPM.Asset) Or IsNull(Form_frmAddPM.Location) Then
    MsgBox "Please enter a value in an asset or location."
    Cancel = True
  End If


 If IsNull(Form_frmAddPM.Supervisor) Or IsNull(Form_frmAddPM.Lead) Or 
    IsNull(Form_frmAddPM.Crew) Or IsNull(Form_frmAddPM.Work_Group) Or 
     IsNull(Form_frmAddPM.Crew_Work_Group) Then
     MsgBox "Please enter value in Supervisor, Lead, Crew, Work Group, or 
     Crew 
        Work Group."
        Cancel = True

      End If

End Sub
```